Availability of source images for Ubuntu 24.04
I am looking for downloading source images of Ubuntu 24.04 but they are not yet uploaded on https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/
I can see Ubuntu 22.04 https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/jammy/release/source/ and Ubuntu 20.04 https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/focal/release/source/ were uploaded in 4 months after their release.
Does anyone has a idea when will the source images for Ubuntu 24.04 might get uploaded?
Thanks in advance.

This question is similar to: How to download the source packages for all installed packages?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
